# Get Records on the basis of list of string Criteria Query Predicates

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, hibernate-criteria

I created one class

`class Employee { Integer id; String name; String departments; }`

and in sql server database i have records
I stored departments as ";" separated. For Example Department = Computer;Civil

- 1,Chaitanya,Computer;Civil
- 2,Tom,Physics;Chemistry
- 3,Harry,Economics;Commerce
- 4,Henry,Computer;Civil;Mechanical
- 5,Ravi,null

Now i want to filter data with departments let's say there is one multiselect in frontend where i have list of departments and i select two departments for example-> Computer,Civil and in backend i got `List<String> deparmentFilter` as parameter say Computer;Civil

Now as per my requirement i have to return two data from Spring Boot Controller

- 1,Chaitanya,Computer;Civil
- 4,Henry,Computer;Civil;Mechanical

Right Now what i did is i executed the query to fetch all the records and then i right below logic

```
List<Employee> employeesToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();
if (!departmentNames.isEmpty()) {
    allEmployees.forEach(employee -> {
        if (employee.getDepartment() != null) {
            Set<String> departmentNamesResult = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(employee.getDepartment().
                    split(";")));
            Boolean isExist = Collections.disjoint(departmentNamesResult, departmentNames);
            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(isExist)) {
                employeesToBeRemoved.add(employee);
            }
        } else {
            employeesToBeRemoved.add(employee);
        }
    });
}
allEmployees.removeAll(employeesToBeRemoved);
```

I tried to move it to predicates but not able to do that, This solution is taking much time to execute,
Please suggest me some other better ways (optimized way) to improve performance.
Is there is any way to add this filter in predicates?

```
Another approach i am thinking (12/05/2022) 
Let's say i have one table employee_department_mapping and in that table i have employeeId and departmentName so in this correct way to add predicate?

 

    CriteriaQuery<Object> subQuery1 = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
    Root<EmployeeDepartmentMapping> subQueryEmpDptMp = subQuery1.from(EmployeeDepartmentMapping.class);
    predicates1.add(subQueryEmpDptMp.get("departmentName").in(departmentNames));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might achieve better performance by splitting your table and using join:
`class Employee { Integer id; String name; Integer departmentsId; }`
`class EmployeeDepartments { Integer departmentsId; String department; }`
You may use [Element Collection](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection) to achieve this.

Now, instead of having a the following row:

```
1,Chaitanya,Computer;Civil
```

You will have the following:

```
table1:
1,Chaitanya,123

table2:
123,Compter
123,Civil
```

Execute a join to get all row from table2 with table1 to get your result

Comment: I don't want to split it into another table

Comment: Let's say i have one table employee_department_mapping and in that table i have employeeId and departmentId 
so in this case how can i use predicate?